# How to: A ListBox from two sources?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, listbox, linq-to-entities

I am using EF with WPF.
How should I create a ListBox that shows both Contacts and Persons?
My question is rather how to retrieve it and create the CollcetionViewSource(s).

I know I will have to use ItemTemplateSelector, that's less what I care, what I really care is the retrieval, but any tips on the representation will be welcommed as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) class.

Comment: WOW, I thought the solution is much more complex!
Thanks!!